# C++ searching text file for a particular string and returning the line number where that string is on

Tags: c++, search, return

Is there a particular function in c++ that can return the line number of a particular string i want to find?

```
ifstream fileInput;
int offset;
string line;
char* search = "a"; // test variable to search in file
// open file to search
fileInput.open(cfilename.c_str());
if(fileInput.is_open()) {
    while(!fileInput.eof()) {
        getline(fileInput, line);
        if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos) {
            cout << "found: " << search << endl;
        }
    }
    fileInput.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file.";
```

I want to add some codes at:

```
    cout << "found: " << search << endl;
```

That will return the line number followed by the string that was searched.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a counter variable to keep track of the current line number.  Each time you call `getline` you... read a line... so just increment the variable after that.

```
unsigned int curLine = 0;
while(getline(fileInput, line)) { // I changed this, see below
    curLine++;
    if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos) {
        cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
    }
}
```

Also...

`while(!fileInput.eof())`

should be

`while(getline(fileInput, line))`

If an error occurs while reading `eof` will not be set, so you have an infinite loop.  `std::getline` returns a stream (the stream you passed it) which can be implicitly converted to a `bool`, which tells you if you can continue to read, not only if you are at the end of the file.

If `eof` is set you will still exit the loop, but you will also exit if, for example, `bad` is set, someone deletes the file while you are reading it, etc.

Comment: oh my i cant believe i didnt think of that simple counter method. i was thinking that there is a special function to call.. thanks i solved it.

Comment: @JohnMarston: No problem, make sure you change that loop condition though.  As it stands you cannot handle an error condition.

Answer (score 6):

A modified version of the accepted answer. [A comment on the answer as a suggestion would have been preferable but I can't comment yet.]
The following code is untested but it should work

```
for(unsigned int curLine = 0; getline(fileInput, line); curLine++) {
    if (line.find(search) != string::npos) {
        cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
    }
}
```

for loop makes it slightly smaller (but perhaps harder to read). And 0 in [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) should be unnecessary because find by default searches the whole string