# find( ") in Text file c++

Tags: c++, find

I have a simple problem:
I want to use the .find method for searching for the " Symbol in a text file. Since you normally write example.find("a") for example, it's not possible to search for the " Symbol. 
Any advice how I can fix this?

Comment: Escape the quote char `.find("\"");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ string literals escape character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220401/c-string-literals-escape-character)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are referring to the C++ language, since that's what your title is called and you've tagged c++ with your question.

Simply, the solution is to do this:

```
    example.find("\""); // The markup shows that this is a valid line of code. See the line below this one to compare the 2.
```

This is because when you would do just this:

```
    example.find("""); // You can already see here using the marking how this will cause a compilation error
```

The compiler would see the first 2 apostrophes as a string in itself; an empty string. However, the third apostrophe would cause a problem as there would be no terminating apostrophe for it, which will cause a compilation error.

Simply to avoid these problems, we use the `example.find("\"");` notation to represent the apostrophe. This is the proper syntax for finding the " symbol as it avoids any conflicts with the other syntax rules of C++. This syntax is often referred to as an escape literal, named as such because it "escapes" a conflict with the general c++ syntax, avoiding a compilation error just as I said above.

On a side note, you will often encounter the backslash () in many other scenarios. For example, consider the following other examples of escape sequences:
 * \n
 * \t
 * \a
 * etc...

These are also escape literals, because without the backsash, they are simply processed as chars or strings. However, with the backslash character, they serve another purpose such as a new line, a tab key, etc...

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @gamma Here's how you can appreciate my answer: [__"What should I do if someone accepts my answer?"__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)   :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer the question without knowing what language you are in.

However, their is a chance that you can use backslash escaping.
For example you would write `example.find("\"")`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I've postet the question in C++. I will change it immediately. Anyhow I think the last user answered my problem so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at it, It will help for sure,
[Link for C++ ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463750/c-searching-text-file-for-a-particular-string-and-returning-the-line-number-wh)  and [link for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418319/find-a-string-or-a-line-in-a-txt-file-java) .

One golden tip, include  **language in tag** .